# Marketing Cloud Journey Builder PB/Flow on Contacts Causing CPU Limit Issues

Tags: marketing-cloud, visual-workflow, journeybuilder, process-builder, cpulimit

In our Org, the JBSystemFlow_Contact flow is being called by a Process Builder every time a Contact is saved, and causing us to hit the CPU Governor Limit. I know that CPU limits can come from anywhere, and that in this case JBSystemFlow is only the last thing that happened when the limit was reached.

**However, when I de-activate this Process Builder/Flow:**

- Individual Contact records save up to 24% faster
- A bulk update of 200 contacts which previously failed for CPU Limit updated without issues
- A bulk update of 20,000 contacts happened 10 minutes faster than with JBSystemFlow_Contact turned on
- There was a 100% reduction in bulk records failing to update due to CPU Limits. 16,000 records failed prior to disabling, and 0 failed after disabling

I'm new to Marketing Cloud, and am hoping someone can help me understand why this flow is running on every Contact save, and why it's causing Contact updates to take so much longer? I found this similar post: [Journey Builder Salesforce Data Event and APEX Governor Limits](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/272357/journey-builder-salesforce-data-event-and-apex-governor-limits) but it doesn't really answer the question

Comment: Is it possible that you have close to 50 active journeys in Marketing Cloud that are based on the Contact object?

Comment: Hi! I couldn't get access to marketing cloud last night to check but I'll check that. When I looked at the flow it only had about 6 decision trees and only 2 action components calling the bulk Apex action, so it didn't seem like it was doing a lot of heavy lifting inside the flow